# Django manage.py dumpdata fails, when model with managed=False

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with `managed=False` in its `Meta` class.

```
class Modelname(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed=False
```

When I execute `python manage.py dumpdata` I get :

```
CommandError: Unable to serialize database: no such table: recruiterbox_modelname
```

How should I backup data from database using Django ?

Comment: The table doesn't exist. So Django can't dump the data as it expects to do.

Comment: I know that Django will not create table for that model. But while datadump it should handle that.

Comment: Not really, `managed=False` only means Django won't create / modify the table. By having this model in your code Django still expects there to be a table and that table is not there. Hence `dumpdata` gives an error.